# java.util.Calendar format mm/dd/yyyy and hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, calendar

For my java program, I have imported the Calendar class and created a getInstance() called cal. The code below is in its own method and class.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I am trying to add to the String coverage, which will be equal to the code below.

```
coverage = String.format("%nPAYOUT FOR EARTHQUAKE DAMAGE"
                           + "%n%SHomeowner:  " + insured
                           + "%nDate:  " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE)
                           + "%nTime:  " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

This returns only the current day and hour. How can I make it where it returns the format

Date: mm/dd/yyyy

Time: hh:mm:ss

Comment: [`Calendar#getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) - but you'll need to format the result based on your needs

Comment: Read up on the `SimpleDateFormat` class.  It's an obsolete class that works nicely with the `Calendar` class.  It's a shame you have to use `Calendar`, because as Basil pointed out, the newer date and time classes are much better.  I hope you're not a student, in an institution that's still teaching `Calendar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *java.time*

You are using a terrible date-time class that was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Capture the current moment as seen in a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now() ;  // Uses JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or, specify time zone explicitly.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

In Java 15+, we have [text blocks](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378) feature to make your text creation easier. Text blocks do not support [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) directly. Use [`String#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))/[`String#formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)).

```java
String insured = "Bob";
String template =
        """
        PAYOUT FOR EARTHQUAKE DAMAGE
        Homeowner: %1$s
        Date: %2$s
        Time: %3$s
        """;
String coverage =
        template.formatted(
                insured ,
                zdt.format(
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.US )
                ) ,
                zdt.format(
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.US )
                )
        );

System.out.println( "coverage = " + "\n" + coverage );
```

When run.

```
coverage = 
PAYOUT FOR EARTHQUAKE DAMAGE
Homeowner: Bob
Date: Feb 27, 2022
Time: 3:20:32 PM
```

### Interoperating with legacy code

If you must use `Calendar` class to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back and forth. Use new conversion methods added to the old classes.

Converting from legacy to modern. Cast to `GregorianCalendar`. Test with `instanceof` if any chance of a different concrete class.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ( ( GregorianCalendar ) calendar ).toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Converting from modern to legacy.

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

If working from a textbook or tutorial using `Calendar`, you need a more recent textbook or tutorial.

Comment: I am tasked to use this class. Not much freedom in changing it.

Comment: You can convert to and fro using new methods added to the old classes.